# How to search for a user within a given AD group?

Tags: powerapp, office-365-groups

Environment SPO. Powerapps. How can I do a search (like people search) within a given AD Security group. I tried below but it's not working.

```
Filter(
SortByColumns(
    Office365Groups.ListGroupMembers(
        "w8c21r37-2110-6348-a1q7-230994ea12wq",
        {top: 999}
    ).value,
    "displayName",
    "Ascending"
),displayName in cmbPeoplePicker.SearchText

)
```